# what is EKEvent on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application.

I read the [document published by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009566-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

However, I have not idea of the EKEvent, can anyone explain more to me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EKEvent and eventWithEventStore is used to add/modify events in your calendar app. Use its properties to get/set event's title and descriptions.

```
An EKEvent object represents an event added to a calendar in Event Kit.

Use the eventWithEventStore: method to create a new event. Use the properties in the class to get and modify certain information about an event.

You can add and remove alarms from an event with the addAlarm: and removeAlarm: methods.
```

Maybe you can tell me what you would like to do?

Comment: @futureelite7, thank you for your reply. I would like to download some data in the CalDAV server and added in the iPhone calendar. Is it possible? or Apple does not provide such API? thank you.

Comment: By any chance, are you trying to sync your Google calendar to your iPhone (or something similar)? There is built in support for syncing google calendar to your iPhone.

Comment: @futureelite, thank you for your reply. I am not trying to sync the Google Calendar. I just want to write such program.